# blitz.js: ctx.session is undefined in login mutation on deployment (works locally)

Tags: session, vercel, blitz.js

In `app/auth/mutations/login` the `ctx` is an empty object (`{}`), thus this line:

```
await ctx.session.$create({ userId: user.id, role: user.role as Role });
```

trhows an `Error: Cannot read property '$create' of undefined`.

Only happens on vercel deployment, works fine on localhost.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mikemmb73 sadly, no

Comment: @eagor please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you use HTTPS or HTTP ? The regular blitz config does not allow the session to be stored in non secure cookies.